# Angular class ng-star-inserted overwrite my class

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a basic select element. I'm trying to give it a class with some attributes but the problem is that my class is overwritten by an angular class "ng-star-inserted". How can I force the element to take my class?
HTML:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Cars</mat-label>
  <select matNativeControl required>
    <option value="volvo" [ngClass]="{'test':isBold}">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</mat-form-field>
```

CSS:

```
.test{ //I tried here with ::ng-deep before the class but it's not working
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

TS:

```
//...code
isBold:boolean=true; //always true for now
```

Comment: Not sure what's the issue with your code, but does this work for you? `<option [class.test]="isBold">...`?

Comment: If that's not working as well... Could you check if `isBold` is available and set to the right value in the HTML?

Comment: It's not. The issue is that my class is not taken. Like it's not used . If I inspect the element in my browser, doesn't have my class.

Comment: Yeah then please debug if `isBold` is available. You can just write it somewhere with `{{ isBold }}`

Comment: It's available.

Comment: Can you share the generated DOM of the volvo element?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select

You may find this helpful

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do you want text to be bolded after option is selected, or during the dropdown display?

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding **!important** for the compiler to prioritize your code. If it doesn't work, try with **::ng-deep** and **!important**

```
.test{
   font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

or

```
::ng-deep.test{
   font-weight: bold !important;
}
```